# Rights to edit "Archives Grothendieck"

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, soft-question, ho.history-overview, mathematical-writing

The [Archives Grothendieck](https://grothendieck.umontpellier.fr/) are now "Archives en accès libre", I would like to know if one can edit them...

I would like to take an excerpt (split some pages of the archive i.e. from page 10-30 of motifs) of an archive and join its tex version in a single archive. Are there legal issues with editing the material..?

At the end my intention is to begin to type som parts of the archives publicly.

[Mentions légales](http://www.umontpellier.fr/mentions-legales)

Comment: You might be interested in posting your question to the "Archives" mailing list https://listes.umontpellier.fr/sympa/subscribe/archives-grothendieck

Comment: @tttbase thanks for pointing out this mailing list! Have subscribed...

Answer (score 12):

Contact me at michele.bolognesi@umontpellier.fr and we shall discuss the details. In the meanwhile I'll hear from the staff of the university how to deal with this.

Best,
Michele

Answer (score 10):

I am not a lawyer, but it seems to me that the problem is not the editing but publication of the material:

> La reproduction de tout ou partie de ce site sur un support électronique quel qu’il soit est formellement interdite sauf autorisation expresse du directeur de la publication.

You can do whatever you want with the material for your own private use, but putting the result on the internet would be a no-no, unless the rights-holders tell you it's OK.  I suggest you contact them: communication@umontpellier.fr.

Comment: Given the initial reluctance of Grothendieck's heirs regarding his _gribouillis_, this is the only sensible course of action.